# How to send async emails with mail_form gem and sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, mail-form

I'm using mail_form gem and have the following code

```
 def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    @contact.request = request
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.deliver
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thank you for your message."}
      else
        format.html {render :new, error: "There was a problem with sending your message."}
      end
    end
  end
```

When I submit my contact form, it takes a few seconds to send a message and redirect to home page.

How to make this process async using sidekiq?

Comment: got the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639073/mail-form-gem-with-sidekiq-worker. The topic can be closed and treated as duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Set up Sidekiq as backend for Active Job
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

And then use the deliver_later method from ActionMailer

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html#method-i-deliver_later