# mail_form gem with sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

How to make **mail_form** gem work with sidekiq worker?
https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form

I'm probably doing something wrong but this code throws me NoMethodError

-**contact_worker.rb**

```
class ContactWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(c)
    c.deliver
  end
end
```

-**contacts_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    @contact.request = request
    ContactWorker.perform_async(@contact)    
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

-

```
2015-07-26T19:12:46.746Z 5785 TID-oxh33etuc ContactWorker JID-014a6a9987980a03f49c355c INFO: start
2015-07-26T19:12:46.747Z 5785 TID-oxh33etuc ContactWorker JID-014a6a9987980a03f49c355c INFO: fail: 0.001 sec
2015-07-26T19:12:46.749Z 5785 TID-oxh33etuc WARN: {"class"=>"ContactWorker", "args"=>["#<Contact:0x007fcf4ef713e8>"], "retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "jid"=>"014a6a9987980a03f49c355c", "created_at"=>1437937936.264524, "enqueued_at"=>1437937966.741929, "error_message"=>"undefined method `deliver' for \"#<Contact:0x007fcf4ef713e8>\":String", "error_class"=>"NoMethodError", "failed_at"=>1437937936.284221, "retry_count"=>1, "retried_at"=>1437937966.747125}
2015-07-26T19:12:46.749Z 5785 TID-oxh33etuc WARN: NoMethodError: undefined method `deliver' for "#<Contact:0x007fcf4ef713e8>":String
2015-07-26T19:12:46.749Z 5785 TID-oxh33etuc WARN: /Users/______/Desktop/______/app/workers/contact_worker.rb:5:in `perform'

.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:75:in `execute_job'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in process'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127:in `block in invoke'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:in `call'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:74:in `call'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:15:in `block in call'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:30:in `with_context'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in `call'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:132:in `call'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:132:in `invoke'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:51:in `block in process'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:98:in `stats'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:50:in `process'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `public_send'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `dispatch'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:122:in `dispatch'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:60:in `block in invoke'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:71:in `block in task'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:357:in `block in task'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:57:in `block in initialize'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:15:in `block in create'
```

Comment: why `< ActionMailer::Base` this is needed ?

Comment: Please post mailform class

Comment: @RajarshiDas updated the posting. If I remove it I get the same error but with 'deliver' meth instead of 'new'

Comment: Its a `WARN` not an `ERROR`.   Does that warning creating any issue?

Comment: Also, watch this http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq for some tips - it says to pass `id` of object instead of whole object to `perform_async`

Comment: @WandMaker I already have other workers in my project(i know how to use them). The problem is, I just don't know how to make this gem work with worker.  btw I found a tutorial on how to make a contact form with default mailer https://www.codefellows.org/blog/how-to-set-up-a-rails-4-2-mailer-with-sidekiq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worker and mailer should be two separate classes.

Comment: I don't have any mailers. Only mail_form gem

Comment: Sounds like you've found your problem.

Comment: haha, thanks! I just thought I don't need to use any mailers with this gem since it works normally ootb.